# How to update Python to the latest version on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, updates, xubuntu, python

The current version of python I've now which is installed by default with Ubuntu is 2.7rc1 ,
Is it possible to update it officially to the latest version (3.7.1) ?

Thank You .

Comment: Python 3.x is contained in the package called "python3".  [Currently](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python3), it looks like it is version 3.6.5.  You can have this package and Python 2 co-existing.

Comment: What are the results of `python3 -V` ? They should show that you already have  Python 3.6.6 installed in 18.04.

Comment: @Ray I think you should change your comment to an answer to the question

Comment: Thanks for your attention, I'm a new Ubuntu user, Can you please explain in detail what should I exactly do ?

Comment: You should read the duplicate question link. Asking us to "explain in detail" something that we have *already* explained in detail seems a bit...um....

Comment: @AhmedAshraf I hope what I said below helps.  But, if you're a new Ubuntu user then I don't suggest you dive into the latest Python.  I think for your needs, any Python 3.x will do.  If you reach a stage where you're more familiar with Ubuntu and the latest version in the repository isn't good enough for you, then you can consider the latest release.  I presume when you reach that stage, you are purposely after features in 3.7.1 that isn't in 3.6.5 .  If you don't know (or care) about the difference, then below should help you.

Comment: @karel It is possible that someone does not have Python 3 installed.  Unlikely but possible.  But I added information about locating the Python 3 executable in my answer.  Thanks!

Comment: @user535733 I'm sorry for this, I already read the duplicate question and there was some terms I didn't understand like ( apt-get, source tar ball, pseudo package, PPA , ... etc ), But I followed the instructions in the answer below and  everything is fine now, Thank you :)

Comment: @AhmedAshraf You're welcome!  Unfortunately, I wrote a slightly longer reply in response to your query for more information, but it got deleted by moderators.  But I'm glad you were able to get the information you needed!

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Outdated:

Python 3.7.1 is still in maintenance version. It is only available for download to Windows and macOS users. Once the stable version is released, then it is made available in Linux repositories. For Windows and Mac users visit [this python.org URL](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-371/).

Currently (2022):

For Linux users: you can download the 3.11.0 version from the terminal

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install python3.11
```

Check the most recent Python version available here: https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: There is a [newer python stable](https://www.python.org/downloads/source/) now than this answer.

Comment: just change the second command to the latest stable version instead of python3.7, currently 3.8

Comment: 2024 - This doesn't work, just says it can't find it.